# incompatible types required:boolean found:int

Tags: java

I think the problem is somewhere in the if statements but I can't figure out whats wrong. as you can see i'm using == and not = as is commonly the issue with this error message. I can't see what else would be wrong with them.

```
Student.java:47: error: incompatible types
        if (Test=1)
                ^
  required: boolean
  found:    int
Student.java:49: error: incompatible types
        if (Test=2)
                ^
  required: boolean
  found:    int
Student.java:51: error: incompatible types
        if (Test=3)
                ^
  required: boolean
  found:    int
3 errors
```

Class:

```
public class Student 
{
private String firstName, lastName;
private Address homeAddress, schoolAddress; 
public double test1, test2, test3;
public double Average;


public Student (String first, String last, Address home, Address school)
{
firstName = first;
lastName = last;
homeAddress = home;
schoolAddress = school;
test1 = 0.0;
test2 = 0.0;
test3 = 0.0;
}

public String toString()
    {
    String result; 

    result = firstName +" "+ lastName+"\n";
    result+= "School Address:\n" + homeAddress + "\n";
    result+= "School Address:\n" + schoolAddress;
    result+= "test one score:\n" +test1;
    result+= "test two score:\n" +test2;
    result+="test three score:\n" +test3;
    result+= "Average test score:\n"+Average;
    return result; 
    }

public void setTestScore(int Test, double Score) 
    {
    if(Test==1)
    { test1=Score; }
    if(Test==2)
    { test2=Score; }
    if(Test==3)
    { test3=Score; }
    }


public double getTestScore(int Test)
    {
    if (Test=1) 
    return test1;
    if (Test=2)
    return test2;
    if (Test=3) 
    return test3;
    }

public double calcAverage()
{
Average = ((test1+test2+test3)/3); 
}
}
```

Comment: "*i'm using == and not =...*" Look again.

Comment: You didn't fix them all - see your `getTestScore` method.

Comment: Look in `getTestScore`.

Answer (score 2):

In `getTestScore`, in `if (Test=1)` this part `Test=1` is an assignment of an int, and its type is also int. You cannot use it as condition in an if statement. Java needs a boolean value as a condition.

Comment: +1 Additionally, `calcAverage()` should return something or the code won't compile.

Answer (score 0):

Watch the == vs =

```
{
if (Test=1) 
return test1;
if (Test=2)
return test2;
if (Test=3) 
return test3;
}
```